# Python unimplemented methods versus abstract methods, which is more pythonic? PyCharm doesn't like methods not implemented in the base class

Tags: python, abstract, pycharm

I have a specific problem closely related to PyCharm (Community 3.1.1). The following simple example illustrates this. I will use the screenshot of PyCharm rather than type the code, for reasons that will be clear shortly.

[image]

As you can see, the call to `self.say_hello()` is highlighted in yellow by PyCharm, and presumably this is because `say_hello()` is not implemented in the `Base` class. The fact that `say_hello()` is not implemented in the base class is intentional on my part, because I want a kind of "abstract" effect, so that an instance of `Base` cannot call `say_hello()` (and therefore shouldn't call `hello()`), but that an instance of `Child` can call `hello()` (implemented in the `Base` class). How do I get this "abstract" effect without PyCharm complaining?

As I learned from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856963/abstract-methods-in-python), I could use the `abc` module. But that, to me, would be rather cumbersome and somewhat not pythonic. What are your recommendations?

Comment: Using abstract method seems the only appropriate solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would implement `say_hello()` as a stub:

```
class Base(object):
    # ...as above...

    def say_hello(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

Alternatively, put only pass in the body of `say_hello()`.

This would also signal to the user of your `Base` class that `say_hello()` should be implemented before she gets an AttributeError when calling `obj.hello()`.
Whether to raise an Exception or to `pass` depends on whether doing nothing is sensible default behaviour.  If you require the user to supply her own method, raise an exception.