# Unused argument in parent class, that is used in subclass. Bad policy?

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, software-design

I have a parent class with an unused argument in private function `_f(i)`

```
class Parent:
    def _f(i):
        return range(m)

    def g():
        for i in range(n)
            for j in _f(i)
                # do something
```

which is intended to be used in overriden method in subclasses

```
class Child:
    def _f(i):
        return range(i, m)
```

Having an unused argument feels ugly, but it saves me from code duplication in method `g()`. Is there any suggested way to avoid it, or should I leave it as it is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the objective is to reuse the code in the `g` function such that the range of the second `for` loop can be changed through class extension. A better solution would be to get rid of the `i` parameter from the `f` function altogether and use *instance* variables instead.

**Parent class**

```
class Parent:
    def _f():
        return range(m)

    def g():
        for i in range(n)
            for j in _f()
                # do something
```

**Child class**

```
class Child:
    def __init__(self, i):
         self.i = i

    def _f():
        return range(self.i, m)
```

An immediate advantage of this approach would be that the contract for the `f` function doesn't need to be changed if one chooses to add more inputs that need to be used within the function in the future.

**Note :** This question has been marked as language agnostic. Any syntactical errors in the above code are intentional.

Answer (score 0):

In some OOP oriented languages like Java or C# there are abstract methods that would delegate the implementation to the child class, however in python the only way to use them is with the `abc` package, the other way to do it would be with interfaces.

Relevant question [Abstract methods in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856963/abstract-methods-in-python)