# Closest thing to a virtual call in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, abstract-class, virtual-functions

Python does not provide some built-in inheritance mechanism to call implementations of base virtual or abstract methods in the derived class from the base methods

I am wondering what is the closest thing in python that would provide the following structure:

```
class Base(?):
   def some_abstract_interface(self, **params):
     raise Unimplemented()
   def some_base_impl(self):
     self.some_abstract_interface(self, a=4, b=3, c=2)


class Derived(Base):

   @neat_override_decorator_here? 
   def some_abstract_interface(self, **params):
     print("actual logic here {0}".format(params))

d = Derived()
d.some_base_impl()
>>>output: actual logic here a=4, b=3, c=2
```

Comment: You might consider using closures, and store them in some fields, then implemening your own virtual dispatch mechanism.

Comment: Could you clarify what the code is supposed to do?

Comment: `abc` (the abstract base class module) has a abstract method decorator [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5856963/8150685). What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: for an instance of `Derived`,  `self.some_abstract_interface` on `Base.some_base_impl` must resolve to the implementation in `Derived`, not the one on `Base`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can already do that without any neat decorator:

```
class Base:
    def some_abstract_interface(self):
        raise NotImplemented

    def some_base_impl(self):
        self.some_abstract_interface()

class Derived(Base):
    def some_abstract_interface(self):
        print('actual logic here')

Derived().some_base_impl()
```

This outputs:

```
actual logic here
```

If you want to enforce that `Base` is an abstract class and cannot be used to instantiate an object directly, and that `some_abstract_interface` is meant to be an abstract method and always has to be overridden by an implementation of the method from a child class, you can make the base class inherit from the `ABC` class of the `abc` module and decorate abstract methods with `abc.abstractmethod` like this:

```
import abc

class Base(abc.ABC):
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def some_abstract_interface(self):
        raise NotImplemented

    def some_base_impl(self):
        self.some_abstract_interface()

class Derived(Base):
    def some_abstract_interface(self):
        print('actual logic here')

Derived().some_base_impl()
```

Comment: that `abc` module looks like what I'm looking for

Answer (score 4):

You simply make the call yourself. That's not going to be any heavier, syntactically, then the decorator you posit.

```
class Derived(Base):
    def some_abstract_interface(self, **params):
        self.some_base_impl()
        print('actual logic her {0}.format(params))
```

In fact, you don't even need to separate `some_base_impl` and `some_abstract_interace`; an abstract method can have an implementation but still require overriding.

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class Base(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def some_abstract_interface(self, **params):
        pass  # Put base implementation here


class Derived(Base):
    def some_abstract_interface(self, **params):
        super().some_abstract_interface(**params)
        print("actual logic here {0}".format(params))
```